# Using SharePoint as a replacement for SalesForce or SAP?

Tags: workflow

Our Company is planning to shift all of their Automated Sales-System to SharePoint.

Is it possible ? I mean, does SharePoint offer any Sales related functionality (like we have in SaleForce or in SAP) ?

Googling the web didn't return me any satisfactory answers.

Answer (score 1):

According to my own Search:

SharePoint is basically a Team Collaboration Portal.

It best works for Document Management, HR, Websites, Workflows and Business Intelligence.

But it currently lacks the full ‘Sales and Distribution’ (SnD) Workflow. To make SnD available in SharePoint, it needs comprehensive Custom Development.

Comment: SharePoint is a box of Legos; you can but have to built your adventures yourself. SalesForce / SAP are ready made toys